# How to redirect a domain + port to a simple domain in Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, dns, instance

I have a VPN running on amazon, now it's working with a simple domain, like www.domain.com, but i'm running a custom aplication called Openerp in 8069 port, so i need to enter www.domain.com:8069 to have acces to my app. I would love to acceso just tipyng www.domain.com

So the question is... can i redirect the domain with port to a simple domain??

Extra information:

Server with ubuntu 13.10, with Openerp running on amazon instance.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

DNS does not know about "ports", so it will not be in the DNS level. You will need some machine to listen to port 80 and do the redirect (or a reverse proxy).

The simplest solution would be to have your openrp listen on port 80. Why is it not doing that?

Another possible solution is to have *another* process on your host listen to port 80 and do either a redirect or a reverse proxy. There are simple Apache and nginx configurations to do that.

Another trivial solution is to have an /etc/services entry do that -- a simple TCP pass-thru from port 80 to port 8069.

Finally, you could use an external host (another host) to do that, with the obvious suggestion being an EC2 load balancer. Just configure the load balancer to fwd traffic to port 80 on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Nitzan, i was reading a lot about the options... openerp cant use port 80 because  i need root access for the service (Not recomendable), there is a way to jump that:http://www.wensley.org.uk/info#setpcaps, perhaps this is a good option.

About apache and ngix, i prefer not to add more services to the server, just the absolutly necesary, but maybe in the future i will use ngix to use SSL and to fix this too.

The /etc/services option sounds better, i'll probably will use this one, or maybe the Load balancer from amazon, i just need to check if that its not going to be very expensive, beacuse i will have 2 VPN's at the same time in my billings!....

Thanks for he help!